# https link in flash banner not working

Tags: flash, https, hyperlink, banner

Good evening everybody,
I am at my wit's end with this specific problem. I have a flash banner and i am using AS 2.0. The code embedded in the flash banner works with any url other that the one i am trying to embed.

Here is the code i am using:

on (press)
{
getURL("https://wcc.webeventservices.com/eventRegistration/EventLobbyServlet?target=registration.jsp&cb=&tile=false&eventid=277065&sessionid=1&key=2BB8C95B8767FEFAC57D086296B4BE6D&cb=blank&sourcepage=register
","_blank");
}

Somehow flash does not like https links. It works fine with other links. Any thoughts?
Thanks in advance for any help on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Html Page:

You need to set allowScriptAccess to sameDomain or even always if sameDomain doesn’t do the job.

And of course, you need to do that for both the object and the embedtag. For example:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,29,0" width="295" height="240">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
    <param name="movie" value="http://server/flash.swf">
    <param name="quality" value="high">
    <embed src="http://server/flash.swf" quality="high" allowScriptAccess="always" allowFullScreen="false"  pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="295" height="240"></embed>
</object>
```

[source](http://blog.tremend.ro/2008/10/03/link-flash-to-html-page/)